# Quest for a non-inductive proof of the addition theorem of probability.

Tags: probability

The addition theorem of probability states that:
$$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup … \cup A_n) = \sum P(A_i) - \sum P(A_i\cap A_j) + \sum P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k) - … + (-1)^nP(A_1\cap A_2\cap … \cap A_n)$$
Although this result is proved using the method of induction         (as in the case of most textbooks), can it be proved directly?
The only thing which I see is its structural similarity with the  general product of binomials :
$$(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)……(1+\nu) = 1 + (\alpha + \beta + … + \nu) + (\alpha \beta + ……) + ……… + (\alpha \beta \gamma …\nu)$$
However I am unable to get a link between the two. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could decompose the union into disjoint sets. For instance, $A \cup B = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)$. Now rearrange $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)$.

Comment: Of course, that's not really an answer to your question ...

Comment: @Stockfish, I think it may involve polynomial fields and other concepts of linear algebra, when we are looking for the decomposition of the general union operator and further rearrangement.

Comment: @Tusky, Ah, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very statement:

$$ P(A1∪A2∪…∪An)=∑P(Ai)−∑P(Ai∩Aj)+∑P(Ai∩Aj∩Ak)−…+(−1)nP(A1∩A2∩…∩An) $$

is what we arrive at from what we call the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability).

Since you are looking for a non-induction based proof, there exists a proof using the Binomial Theorem [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml) and an algebraic proof using [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Proof_of_main_statement).